# Create a Polygon with Google Maps API from KMZ file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've some KMZ and KML files that define some polygons in Google Earth. Is there a way to read those files with Google Maps API and create the polygons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. KmlLayer will load KMZ files from a valid publicly accessible URL, as long as it meets the [limits](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport).
2. The kmz branch of the third party parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) can render KMZ files as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/buffetthawaiitour_kmz.zip)